# Why is my generic class constructor refusing to take objects implementing the requested Interface

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a generic `Item`-interface and an implementation with a date property like so:

```
public interface Item<T extends Temporal> {
    T getDate();
}

public class SpecialItem implements Item<LocalDateTime> {
    private final LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    public SpecialItem(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return localDateTime;
    }
}
```

Now I have a provider class and interface for said `Item`

```
public interface ItemProvider<T extends Temporal> {
    List<Item<T>> getEntries();
}

public class SpecialItemProvider<T extends Temporal> implements ItemProvider<T> {
    private final List<Item<T>> entries;

    public SpecialItemProvider(List<Item<T>> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item<T>> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}
```

I have the problem that I can not really call the constructor of the `SpecialItemProvider` like so (I really want an object of type `ItemProvider`):

```
@Test
public void genericTest(){
    final List<SpecialItem> dateTimeList =
    Collections.singletonList(new SpecialItem(LocalDateTime.MAX)));
    ItemProvider itemProvider = new SpecialItemProvider<LocalDateTime>(dateTimeList);
}
```

It always fails with the following error message:

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.List<GenericTest.SpecialItem>
cannot be converted to java.util.List<GenericTest.Item<java.time.LocalDateTime>>
```

Which makes me wonder why it is not accepted although `SpecialItem` explicitly implements `Item<LocalDateTime>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @KevinEsche oh well, I'm sorry I forgot to make them all public, the code is from a short self contained example in which I made them all private inner classes. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message makes it clear: in Java a `List<SpecialItem>` is not compatible with `List<Item>` even if `SpecialItem` is indeed a kind of `Item`. Generics in Java are invariant, so in this case you have two options:

- (not suggested) declare `dateTimeList` of type `List<Item>` - it allows you to add `SpecialItem` and is compatible with the ctor signature
- modify the ctor signature to accept a `List<? extends Item<?>>`

Comment: Could you point me into a direction how to convert the parameter of type List<? extends Item<?>> to List<Item<T>> because I really need the generic of the SpecialItemProvider